# Debian with exact Keyboard settings as in Windows 10

Tags: debian, windows, keyboard

I use Windows 10 with an English-Hebrew keyboard. I have basically three modes:

1. Switch between lowercase English and Hebrew: **ALT+SHIFT**.
2. Switch between lowercase English and Uppercase English: **CAPSLOCK**.
3. Switch between Hebrew and Uppercase English: **CAPSLOCK**.

Could I use these exact settings if I install Debian?

Comment: what happens when you use shift on the hebrew?  i assume uppercase english?  the `il` hebrew layout already puts uppercase english on the 2nd level, but i can't say it's the same as windows' version.  see the existing hebrew layouts (`il`, and variants `lyx`, `phonetic`, and `biblical`) defined in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/il`.  you'll want option `grp:alt_shift_toggle`.  all together: `setxkbmap -layout us,il -option grp:alt_shift_toggle`

Comment: You can completely customize your keyboard layout, so you can definitely use those exact settings, but you'll have to figure out how to do it, unless using similar (and not exact) settings is good enough for you. Start with reading [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.600.7058).